# How to create different Classes without conditional statements?

Tags: class, oop, conditional-statements, polymorphism

Ok lets say we have:

```
    Class Humans {
    ...
    }
    
    Class Men extends Humans{
    ...
    }
    
    Class Women extends Humans{
    ...
    }
```

And then we receive a Input from the user and have to create the Class according to this input...

Instead of using:

```
if (userInput = 'men') {
   var obj = new Men()
} else {
   var obj = new Women()
}
```

Is there a way to do it without conditional statements? Because let's say we have 10 different types of classes, it would be hard bad to write it 10 times.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a dictionary mapping the possible user inputs to types, then use reflection to dynamically instantiate objects of the matching type given a user input. You could write your own or use a dependency injection library to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways, each with their own benefits and drawbacks. One naive example would be to have two buttons, the first of which calls `new Women()` when clicked and the other `new Men()`. That is, your conditional has more to do with parsing input text than classes/polymorphism.

Which approach is most appropriate depends on your particular context. Adding more buttons is, of course, seldom a good choice in a real project but showcases the possibility of moving conditional statements out from the code and into the user's hands.